# gulp watch is stopping the end event of task

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch

i had create 4 tasks in gulp where 2 tasks are such that which is dependent on first two one. so i had used the gulp run-sequence to run task in such sequence that task1 and task2 executed first and then task3 and task4.

```
gulp.task('default',function(){
    runSequence(['task1','task2'],'task3','task4');
})
```

even task1 and task2 is sucessfully executed task3 and task4 fail to execute because it wait for task1 and task2 end event . after some effort i came to know that i had put the watch in my task1 and task2 which is preventing the end event of that task and  because of that reason task3 and task4 is not executing

here is my task1 which had watch in pipe process to reflect the changes in file at destination folder when any changes at source is occurred .

```
gulp.task('task1',function(){
     gulp.src([
     projectDirectory+'/**/*.js'
    ])
   .pipe(watch(projectDirectory+'/**/*.js'))
   .pipe(plumber())
   .pipe(uglify())
   .pipe(rename(function(path) {
     path.extname = ".min.js";
   }))
   .pipe(gulp.dest(destination));
})
```

i tried to remove the .pipe(watch(projectDirectory+'/**/*.js')) from task 3 and 4 is sucessfully executed

need a help to figure out the way to execute all of the task sucessfully

Comment: Try adding 'return' before gulp.src of task 1 and 2

Comment: added return but still not working

Comment: Did you add a return to task 3 as well? You will need to make sure that `task1`, `task2`, and `task3` all return before `task4` can be executed.